# Voice quality with vocalist age increased

Tags: vocal-styles

Taking example of Sir Rod Stewart with current age as 75 years, i see the same melody,sweetness in his voice.

What are the different factors attributing to this?

I mean as a singer's (human being) age increases, the voice quality should ideally deteriorate.

Comment: One thing you'll probably find that he's singing lower than he did before.  Robert Plant is another example, if you compare what notes he sings now to the notes he sang with Led Zeppelin (or even from the begging of LZ to the end) you'll notice he drops down a key or two.

Comment: Thanks. Just a wild guess from your side, what will be Sir Rod Stewart's voice according to you after 15 years. i.e. in year 2035. i.e. Sir Rod Steward becomes 90 years old if he continues signing.

Comment: I.e. Sir Rod Stewart sings the same song after 15 years when he will turn 90 years old.

Comment: Talk about it is down a semi-tone from the original, Stay with me is down a tone, which isn't much - but then again compared to some of his other early material they don't have a lot of range requirement. ie, pretty easy songs to sing… & he is struggling to reach Stay with me, ducking the melody in a lot of places.